# Postman : CORS request not allowed

Tags: postman

I'm making this request using Postman:

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: mywebsite.com
Authorization: Basic YXNmYXNmcXdycXJxdzphc2Zhc2Zxd3I=
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

user_id=123123123123&grant=credentials
```

But I always get "403: CORS request not allowed".
What kind of cross-origin request does Postman in background?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the CORS error being reported, but I found a configuration error. I had set Auth URL parameter to http://localhost:9090/core/connect/authorize rather than http://localhost:9090/connect/authorize after I had changed the mapping in my startup. The CORS error was confusing because I had set the options to AllowAllOrigins. Changing the URL to the correct value fixed the problem. Perhaps if you would post your Postman configuration, and the Client setup I could help you find your problem.